# Django with apache in centos 8. don't have permission to access / on this server(newly deployed)

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, centos8

filesystem path '/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Fri Mar 20 06:35:04.536515 2020] [core:error] [pid 8177:tid 140498932373248] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.4:54121] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://192.168.1.2/
[Fri Mar 20 06:36:23.588628 2020] [core:error] [pid 8503:tid 140498958239488] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:53958] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path